# Mysql where clause accepting integer with strings on primary key field

Tags: mysql

In MySql i have a primary key field id, when i do `select * from users where id='12p'` it brings the value of row 12.

Please how do I go about this.

**Updated**
Nodejs sample

```
const { User } = require('models')

User.findOne({where:{id:'12p'}}).then(user => console.log(user))
```

Comment: if id column is a int datatype the result MySQL returns is "correct" because `'12p'` is auto casted to a int by MySQL.. Thats why you should **NOT ever** use single qoutes on a int datatype. Note other database systems will give a error when using single qoutes on a int datatype.

Comment: I am using a ORM in nodejs (sequelize) and give this issue.

Comment: The 12p is in a variable, so do I remove the single quotes?

Comment: Show the node.js code?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: use `User.findOne({where:{id:12}}).then(user => console.log(user))` if you want to query a int

Comment: But the problem is the input value is coming from the user and it will be in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MYSQL, While you put your string values in where clause it parses integer number out of it. For instance, If you put '1abc', it'll parse 1 out of it. Follow the other examples:

```
'abc' => 0,
'2abc' => 2,
'a2bc' => 0,
'1a1bc' => 1
```

I don't know exactly Why does this happen but that's how MySQL works. I myself was struggling with that bug in my job. I had to add some extra logics to get the valid response.